# Overloaded typescript function parameter does not work with async keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm working on a larger project type definition file. I have simplified the code into an isolated example:

Module definition `f.d.ts`

```js
export type myFunction = ((r: string) => Promise<any>) // async def
  | ((r: string, done: (err: Error | null, b?: any) => void) => void) //callback def

export interface addFunc {
  (c: string, f: myFunction): void
}

export interface FI {
  addFunc: addFunc
}

export default function f(): FI
```

Module implementation `f.js`

```js
function f () {
  return {
    addFunc: (c, p) => {
      this[c] = p
      return this
    }
  }
}

module.exports = f
```

Module utilization index.ts

```js
import f from './f'

f().addFunc('x', (r, d) => { // Compiles as expected
  d(null)
})

f().addFunc('x', async (r) => { // Error ts(7006) Parameter 'r' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  return null
})
```

Can you please explain why this error is happening and how I could fix it? I believe the issue is in the type definition.

Please do not comment on the implementation itself; this is an extremely stripped down and isolated piece of a large API.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to

```
f().addFunc('x', async (r: string) => {
  return null
})
```

Without adding `: string`, your function is really a `(r: any) => Promise<null>`, which is not assignable to the type `myFunction`.

The first case in your example compiles because TypeScript is able to infer the types of `r` and `d` by the fact that there're two parameters, which makes it impossible to assign to the first case in the union definition of `myFunction`. But when a function has only one parameter, it could be assigned to a type that has one or more parameters, so TypeScript cannot automatically infer the type of `r`.

Comment: I see, I'll try this and see how it goes. I was hoping TS could infer this based on regular function overload patterns https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#function-overloads

Comment: Marking this is as the correct answer because it is a valid fix. Ideally TS would be able to infer based on function overload; however, I'm not going to get blocked by it right now! Thank you :)